# Android tutorial for implementing scrollable lable with touch

Tags: android, scroll

I want to implement a date scroll label which displays a current date.

Now, user can touch the date and scroll either left or right direction ( something similar to unlock functionality or monthview scroller)

Based on the direction, either previous or next date should be displayed in the label part.
And user can do the same scrolling with multiple times.

Can anyone provide me the link for the tutorial which explains details about implementing such control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for start , http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle/